# Calling psf.js from aura component

Tags: aura

I am trying to call an external library named Mozilla pdf.js from an aura component. I saved the library as static resources, but it is still not calling. What could be the issue?

Below is .cmp file i wrote

```html
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="SampleContClass" access="global">
    <!-- Define your Aura component markup -->
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default="Hello, Flow Builder!" />
    
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', 
        $Resource.pdfjs,
        $Resource.pdfjsworker)}" 
        afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
    
    <div>   
        <button onclick="{!c.handleClick}">Click me</button>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```